# Setting schema for all queries of a connection in Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I want to set namespace(schema) for all query in java I will set in jdbc url in robot framework there is no documentation for it.

JDBC Namespace :

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/cutomer?currentSchema=test123
```

Robot Framework configuration

```
Suite Setup       Connect To Database    psycopg2       ${dbName}     ${dbUsername}    ${dbPassword}      ${dbHost}     ${dbPort}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly it's not possible with robotframework and psycopg2. You should modify `search_path` right after connecting to database.